# SQL question for e-mail thread view

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I would like to query back a list of threads, with each of the conversation showing the latest message `max(date)`, and a count of how many messages in the conversation `count(*), group by threadID`.

Here's the SQL table

```
Message
-------------
messageID (int)
subject (varchar)
...
date (date)
threadID (guid)
```

How do I produce the following in one single query?  in a thread view like in Gmail?

Or is the data structure wrong?  Maybe I should denormalize the required data to a `Thread` table?  Make use of trigger to update the last message ID and count?

Thanks!

**update**
I also need the subject of the 'max([date])', and order the thread by the date of the last message, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `threadID` is a unique link for a conversation, unless I'm missing something, this should work:

```
SELECT threadID, count(messageID) as MessageCount, max([date]) as MaxDate
FROM Message
GROUP BY threadID
```

You may also want to change the `date` column name, since that's a reserved word.

**EDIT for requirements change**

Since you haven't specified if the e-mail subject may change ("Hey" in the first e-mail may be "RE: Hey" in the second for a response), I've done a subquery so you can pull any information from the `Message` table (M1) you want.

```
SELECT M1.subject, M1.date, M2.MessageCount
FROM 
Message M1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT threadID, count(messageID) as MessageCount, 
         max([date]) as MaxDate, max(messageID) as MaxMessageID
    FROM [Message]
    GROUP BY threadID
) M2 ON
M1.threadID = M2.threadID and M1.MessageID = M2.MaxMessageID
ORDER BY M1.[date] DESC
```

Comment: oh, and order the thread by the date of the last message... sorry didn't ask the Q clear enough.

Comment: @Henry - You really should update your question with the requirements.  In any case, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Also, mystery downvoter, what didn't you like about my original answer before the requirements changed?  In case I stated anything wrong, I would like to learn from this and know for the future.